# PHP OOP Login system - member function getUsername() returns NULL

Tags: php, oop, authentication, scope

I'm currently trying to learn the oop approach of a simple PHP Loginsystem connected to a database.

Ive got the a class called User and initialize it with `$user = new User();` in my init.php, which is required_once at the top of my index.php.

```
<?php

    class User {

    private $username;
    private $password;
    private $salt = '1Xi432z';
    private $db;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db = new Database();
    }

    public function setUsername($username) {

        $this->username = $username;
    }

    public function setPassword($password) {

    $this->password = md5($password . $this->salt);
    }

    public function authenticateUser() {

        $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ? AND pwd = ?');
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $this->username);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $this->password);
        $stmt->execute();

        return  $stmt->rowCount() == 1;
    }

    public function getUsername() {

        return $this->username;
    }
  }
```

In my login.php script I set the username and password of $user by calling

`$user->setUsername($_POST['username'])` and `$user->setPassword($_POST['password'])`

then I call the `$user->authenicateUser()` member function to check if the user is able to login.

After the user successfully logged in, I'm trying to get the username with
`<?php echo $user->getUsername() ?>` but it returns nothing.

While trying to debug it, I've learned that the member function is called properly but it thinks that my private variable $username is empty/NULL.

it seems like my object $user is out of scope?? Because when I initialize my user with `$user = new User();` and set it's username in them same file as where I try to echo the username it works perfectly fine. But ofcourse I can't do that, since the object must be already initialized while the login procedure.

I'm trying to figure this problem out for a few days now. So any kind of help would be nice (:

EDIt:

as requested my login.php:

```
<?php

  if ( isset($_POST['login']) ) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $user->setUsername($username);
    $user->setPassword($password);

    if($user->authenticateUser()) {

      $session->set('currentUser', $username);

      header('Location: index.php');
    }
    else {

    $_POST['wrongPassword'] = true;
   }

  }
```

sidenote: this script might not be safe in security aspects at all. But it's also a school assignment, where some things were requested. I wasn't asked to do it object oriented, but I trying it this way

Comment: It should be <?php echo $user->getUsername(); ?>

Comment: You have a typo: `$username->getUsername();` != `$user->getUsername();`. And remove md5() asap!

Comment: Are you trying to echo the username from $user object after refresh ? Post your login code please.

Comment: ah sorry.. the typo was just here.

Comment: should the md5() be in another place? or do u justt think its bad?

Comment: A salt cannot / should never be just a static value. md5 was never meant for hashing passwords and should not be used. Use `password_hash` instead. Your user class has too many responsibilities.

Comment: @Alok yes I was trying to echo it after a refresh. I now tried to store it in a SESSION var. doesn't do the trick.
`$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];`
and then `$user->setUsername($_SESSION['username'])`. same thing. still no output.. but `echo $_SESSION['username']` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding you're trying to display User information after successful login on next page. So here is what you need to do. Save the user's email address in session variable.

```
if($user->authenticateUser()) {
    $_SESSION["username"]=$username;
    header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Now on index.php page you need to create $user object and set the username from the session. `$user->setUsername($_SESSION["username"]);` Don't forget start the session by `session_start()`;

It is good approach to save primary key of User table in session and get the User details from the database. For your assignment it is fine as there are only two fields.